# Group data in header collection view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, collections

How can I group my data received from **firebase** in **header collection view**?

From **firebase** I received **array** with this data:

```
{
    "N7AooUYQU576hb5qLux" : {
        "requested_date" : 20190110,
        "requested_times" : {
            0: 1,
            1: 2,
    }
    "0ckbfkwm2yR0wbcEQ2XT" : {
        "requested_date" : 20190110,
        "requested_times" : {
            0: 3,
            1: 4,
    }
    "38kBVw01kvJtYTtYt0ba" : {
        "requested_date" : 20190211,
        "requested_times" : {
            0: 5,
            1: 6,
    }
    "3bQ3WTwasALxqNNR9P4c" : {
        "requested_date" : 20190315,
        "requested_times" : {
            0: 1,
            1: 2,
    }
    "51OhvSiBGDa0HH8WV5bt" : {
        "requested_date" : 20190211,
        "requested_times" : {
            0: 10,
            1: 11,
    }
}
```

To retrieve data from **firestore** I use this code:

```
var bookingHall: [BookingHall] = []
var document: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

fileprivate func observeQuery() {
    guard let query = query else { return }
    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            self.unknownError(error: err)
        } else {
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                let bookingModel = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> BookingHall in
                    if let newBooking = BookingHall(dictionary: document.data()) {
                        return newBooking
                    } else {
                        fatalError("Fatal error")
                    }
                }
                self.bookingHall = bookingModel
                self.document = snapshot.documents
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return ...
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.bookingHall.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "studioBookCollCell", for: indexPath) as! StudioBookCollectionCell
    let timeStart = self.bookingHall[indexPath.item].requestedTimes.first!
    let timeEnd = self.bookingHall[indexPath.item].requestedTimes.last! + 1
    cell.timeLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:00 - %02d:00", timeStart, timeEnd)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerBook", for: indexPath) as! StudioBookCollectionReusableView
    header.dateLabel.text = ""
    return header
}
```

The end result I would like to see is like the **picture** below:

I have no idea how to group my data and apply to the header and in each of the headers has the correct data in the cells.

Please tell me how it can be done? If need more code I will update my post.

My **struct**:

```
protocol BookingDocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct BookingHall {

    var contactInfo: [String: Any] = [:]
    var creationDate: Timestamp
    var requestedTimes: [Int] = []
    var uid: String = ""
    var hall: String = ""
    var requestedDate: Int = 0

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {

        return [

            "contact_info": contactInfo,
            "creation_date": creationDate,
            "requested_times": requestedTimes,
            "uid": uid,
            "hall": hall,
            "requested_date": requestedDate

        ]
    }
}

extension BookingHall: BookingDocumentSerializable {

    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {

        let contactInfo = dictionary["contact_info"] as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
        let creationDate = dictionary["creation_date"] as? Timestamp
        let requestedTimes = dictionary["requested_times"] as? [Int] ?? []
        let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        let hall = dictionary["hall"] as? String ?? ""
        let requestedDate = dictionary["requested_date"] as? Int ?? 0

        self.init(contactInfo: contactInfo,
                  creationDate: creationDate!,
                  requestedTimes: requestedTimes,
                  uid: uid,
                  hall: hall,
                  requestedDate: requestedDate)    
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: added my struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grouping` for achieving your requirement.

**[init(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init)**

> Creates a new dictionary whose keys are the groupings returned by the
>   given closure and whose values are arrays of the elements that
>   returned each key.

Please refer below code, It is a just idea how you can implement the above requirement so, I request please ignore other syntaxial error.

```
let aryData = [BookingHall]() // Your main array

//Create dicationary with grouped value with `requested_date`
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: aryData, by: { $0.requested_date })

//Format Array for populate data into UITableView
let allKeys = Array(dict.keys)



let aryFinalData = [FinalData]()
for value in allKeys{
    let data = FinalData(title: value, aryData: dict[value]!)
    aryFinalData.append(data)
}


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return aryFinalData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return aryFinalData[section].aryData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cellData = aryFinalData[indexPath.section].aryData[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerBook", for: indexPath) as! StudioBookCollectionReusableView
    let headerData = aryFinalData[indexPath.section]
    header.dateLabel.text = headerData.requested_date
    return header
}
```

**Create a new structure for title and sub Array**

```
struct FinalData{
    let title:String?
    let aryData:[BookingHall]?
}
```

Comment: What means is `dict[dict]!)`?

Comment: Glad to hear!  Happy codding

Answer (score 3):

Create a dictionary to store the grouped data

```
var bookingHall: [BookingHall] = []
var groupedHalls: [Int: [BookingHall]] = [:]
```

After assigning values to self.bookingHall array group the data by the date

```
self.bookingHall = bookingModel
groupedHalls = Dictionary(grouping: bookingHall, by: { $0.requestedDate })
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Use this dictionary in collectionview data source methods

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return groupedHalls.keys.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return groupedHalls[Array(groupedHalls.keys)[section]]?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let bookingHalls = groupedHalls[Array(groupedHalls.keys)[indexPath.section]]
    let bookingHall = bookingHalls[indexPath.row]
    let timeStart = bookingHall.requestedTimes.first!
    let timeEnd = bookingHall.requestedTimes.last! + 1
    cell.timeLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:00 - %02d:00", timeStart, timeEnd)
    print(bookingHall)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerBook", for: indexPath) as! StudioBookCollectionReusableView
    header.dateLabel.text = "\(Array(groupedHalls.keys)[indexPath.section])"
    return header
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SupplementaryView described in other comments, but depending on the result you want to achieve, you may consider this option:

Let it be `UITableView` & each `UITableViewCell` will have a `UICollectionView` inside. In this case you can put all your data in `collectionView`'s cells, while the headers will belong to the `tableView`

[image: Answer's description]

What is the benefit in this case? Your whole view is `vertical-scrollable`, but each cell can be independently `horizontal-scrollable`

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your JSON as `[ (Int, [(Int,Int)] ) ]` : Your array will look like :

```
[
    ( 20190110, [(1,2), (3,4)] ),
    ( 20190315, [(1,2)]), 
    ( 20190211, [(5,6), (10-11)] )
]
```

Then in `numberOfSection` you just return `arrayForCollectionView.count`

For the header itself :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerBook", for: indexPath) as! StudioBookCollectionReusableView

    header.dateLabel.text = arrayForCollectionView[indexPath.section].0

    return header
}
```